# Drawing object diagram from rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, uml, rake, rails-migrations

Recently I heard someone suggest that there is a way to map object diagrams from rails migrations by some reverse engineering method.It would be great if someone could actually explain how this is done or using what tool it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rails ERD and UML Diagrams

You can generate [Rails class diagrams](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Rails_Class_Diagrams) for models with [rails-erd](https://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd) or [railroady](http://github.com/preston/railroady). Both gems depend on [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/), so make sure you follow the directions for each gem to make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed first.